# iterating through variable in sql where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got this kind of statement:

```
declare @max int
@max = 1
SELECT @max, t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
```

this will give me results:

```
1 a a
1 b b
1 c c
```

and I would like to get this kind of result

```
1 a a
2 b b
3 c c
```

how can I achieve this result?

I've tried to do as follow:

```
@max = 1
SELECT @max, t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
WHERE @max = @max + 1
```

but with no success, can someone help me with it?
thanks!

PS. I have to use @max as variable - I can not use Identity or AUTOINCREMENT column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the row_number() function.

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by t1.col1, t1.col2),t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
```

Starting from a fixed value :

```
declare @your_number int
set @your_number = 24353

SELECT @your_number + row_number() over (order by t1.col1, t1.col2) AS num,t1.col1, t1.col2
FROM table1 t1
```

Comment: ok, but assuming that I dont want to start from 1... but for ex. from some random int 24353? how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with cte as 
(
  SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, ROW_NUMBER() by (order by t1.col1, t1.col2) as RowNumber
  FROM table1 t1
)

select c.RowNumber, c.col1, c.col2
from cte c
```

`row_number()` function will return row number starting from 1.